# versioned JavaScript file not forcing browser to refresh cache

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

On my Angular JS app I'm forcing the browser to not use the cached version of my `app.min.js` by appending a query string to it with `app.min.js?v1039-190217`

```
<script src="build/js/app.min.js?v1039-190217"></script>
```

But it's not working, I still need to refresh the browser cache for my changes to take effect.

Is there something I'm missing?  Is this a quirk of Angular Js?

Comment: Are you appending a different query string each time you make an update to the app.min.js file? If you append the same query string each time, the browser will cache that specific version.

Comment: @ChrisCousins, yes I'm appending a different query string each time I update the file